# How to pass the %0A in the uri template using the wcf rest service

Tags: rest, wcf

hello everyone I'm trying to create the wcf rest service to upload the comments  but my service will work fine if i use the space but when i use the enter or new line (\n or %oA) in the uri template then the service will give the error like 
**HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.**

```
 [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "comment/{comments}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string comment(string comments);
```

Any suggestions how to solve this issue thanks in advance

Comment: How about not using the query string for posting text?

Comment: hi @CodeCaster can you show some example thanks

Comment: I came to know that the special characters are not allowed in the Uri
 template for the security reason but I found the solution that is now
I'm passing the comments in the HTTP body and it worked for me. I would have posted this as answer but my account has been banned by the way thanks for you suggestion @CodeCaster